# Save range address as cell value, use in later range in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that runs an if-then statement. It asks the user if they would like to re-pick a range, and if not then use the last range picked. I got the first part of it down, but when I store the address of the range, I cant figure out how to call it back. See below for the code.

```
NewNS = MsgBox("Would you like to pick new Force ID's in the North-South direction?", vbYesNo, "Roof North-South")
    If NewNS = vbYes Then
    Worksheets("ShearWalls").Activate
    Do Until CheckNS = vbYes
        On Error Resume Next
        Set rngNS = Application.InputBox("Select your Force ID's (North-South)", "Roof North-South", Type:=8)
        On Error GoTo EndJump
        CheckNS = MsgBox("The cells selected were " & rngNS.Address & " for North-South. Is this correct?", vbYesNo, "Roof North-South")
    Loop
    Worksheets("Reference").Range("B739").Value = rngNS.Address
    Else
        Setrng = Worksheets("Reference").Range("B739").Value
        Set rngNS = Range(Setrng)
    End If
```

I know it can be simplified in some ways, I just want to make sure it works first. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Build your range using the address stored as a cell value. You are using `Worksheets("ShearWalls").Activate` but not qualifying the parent of the address stored in `Range("B739")`.

While it is unclear from your narrative which worksheet you are trying to reference, I'm going to assume that you want thte range from the **Reference** worksheet, not the **ShearWalls** worksheet.

```
with Worksheets("Reference")
    Setrng = .Range("B739").Value2
    Set rngNS = .Range(Setrng)
end with
```

Comment: I'm not sure if the worksheet matters, but that code didn't seem to work. I'll try and describe what I'm trying to do and maybe a different code could work. Lets say I enter `$A$18:$A$20` in cell A1. I want to have my VBA code get whatever cell range I specify in A1, and if I wanted to I could change it manually.

Thanks for your help. @Jeeped

Comment: I think I understood what you meant now @Jeeped.

I changed the `Else` section of code to state

`Else
        Setrng = Worksheets("Reference").Range("B739").Value
        Set rngNS = Worksheets("Shearwalls").Range(Setrng)
    End If`

And go the values I needed. Thanks again.